# mysql query returns false, mysql insert works but echo statement doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, insert, echo

I am making a text-based online game, in my game, there is a battle system. After defeating the enemy you can be awarded a badge if you do not already have said badge. However, for some strange reason that I can not wrap my head around, the badge is added to the database as it should be (if the table row for the badge does not exist on the MySQL database) but the text that should accompany earning the badge shows up sometimes. I would say the echo shows 50% of the time or less. Here is my code:

```
$gettrainerbadge = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM t_badges where 
badge='$badge' AND trainer='$getuser3[username]'");
$gettrainerbadge2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gettrainerbadge);


if(!$gettrainerbadge2)
{
    //This echo shows up maybe 50% of the time the form is submitted.

    echo "<font face='verdana' size='2'><br><br><br><img src='images/badges/$get_gym_leader3[badge].png' style='padding: 10px;'><br>By defeating $getuser3[battle_trainer] you have also earned a(n) $get_gym_leader3[badge] Badge!";


    //This INSERT works as expected when the badge doesn't exist it adds the badge to the database if the badge already exists it does nothing

    $addbadge = "INSERT INTO t_badges (`trainer`, `badge`) VALUES ('$getuser3[username]', '$get_gym_leader3[badge]')"; 
    mysqli_query($conn, $addbadge);

}
```

As I've said the echo statement works half the time, it should work every time and I can not figure out why the badge is being added but the text that accompanies it doesn't show. Any help is appreciated.

---

After playing with the code some more I've noticed that sometimes I can see a VERY fast flash of the page with the image of the badge, so I don't think the above code is to blame. I think it has to do with the following scripts I am using to submit the forms automatically without user feedback. I don't know why they would interfere with each other, but I'm almost certain that there is a double post submission going on somewhere. If anyone could help point out what I might be doing wrong here I would appreciate it.

```
if($get_remaining_opponents3 > '0')
{

print "<form action='index.php?action=battle' method='POST' 
name='attackselect' id='attackselect' style='margin: 0px;'><td width='100%' 
height='50px' style='background: #e6e6e6; border:2px solid #e6e6e6; border-
radius: 25px;'>

<center>

<font face='verdana' size='2'>

<label style='margin-top: 0px;' id='battle_text'>

<input type='radio' name='continue' value='continue' checked>

<i>Resuming battle ... (<span id='continue'> </span>)</i>
</input>
</label>
</form>
";
?>


<script>

var milisec= 0;  
var seconds=4;      

document.getElementById("continue").innerHTML ='4';   
continue_battle() ; 


function continue_battle(){ 
if (milisec<=0){ 
milisec=9; 
seconds-=1; 
} 
if (seconds<=-1){ 
milisec=0; 
seconds+=1; 
} 
else
{ 
milisec-=1; 
document.getElementById("continue").innerHTML =seconds;
setTimeout("continue_battle()",100); 
}
if(document.getElementById("continue").innerHTML == '0')
{
document.getElementById("attackselect").submit();
}
}
</script>

<?php
print "</form>";
}
else
{

print "<form action='index.php?action=battle' method='POST' name='victory' 
id='victorious' style='margin: 0px;'><td width='100%' height='50px' 
style='background: #e6e6e6; border:2px solid #e6e6e6; border-radius: 25px;'>

<center>

<font face='verdana' size='2'>

<label style='margin-top: 0px;' id='battle_text'>

<input type='radio' name='victory' value='$getuser3[opp_level]' checked>

<i>Resuming battle ... (<span id='victory'> </span>)</i>
</input>
</label>
</form>
";
?>


<script>

var milisec= 0;  
var seconds=4;      

document.getElementById("victory").innerHTML ='4';   
victorious() ; 


function victorious(){ 
if (milisec<=0){ 
milisec=9; 
seconds-=1; 
} 
if (seconds<=-1){ 
milisec=0; 
seconds+=1; 
} 
else
{ 
milisec-=1; 
document.getElementById("victory").innerHTML =seconds;
setTimeout("victorious()",100); 
}
if(document.getElementById("victory").innerHTML == '0')
{
document.getElementById("victorious").submit();
}
}
</script>

<?php
print "</form>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$gettrainerbadge = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM t_badges where badge='".$badge."' AND trainer='".$getuser3['username']."'");
$gettrainerbadge2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gettrainerbadge);

if(count($gettrainerbadge2) == 0)
{

     echo "<font face='verdana' size='2'><br><br><br><img src='images/badges/".$get_gym_leader3['badge'].".png' style='padding: 10px;'><br>By defeating ".$getuser3['battle_trainer']." you have also earned a(n) ".$get_gym_leader3[badge]." Badge!";

    //This INSERT works as expected when the badge doesn't exist it adds the badge to the database if the badge already exists it does nothing


    $addbadge = "INSERT INTO t_badges (`trainer`, `badge`) VALUES ('".$getuser3['username']."', '".$get_gym_leader3['badge']."')"; 
    mysqli_query($conn, $addbadge);

}
```

Try using count variable i hope it should work for every match records.

Comment: The count variable will be useful to me in the future, however, it has made no change in how this code is working. Or rather not working..

Comment: please check with echo exit at every variable and check for the output you get try run query in database

Comment: I have run the query with exit, there are no errors with the queries, like I said it all works fine as far as looking for the badge table row, if it doesn't exist it adds the badge to the database. The only part that doesn't work as expected is the text output echo portion.

Comment: It is almost acting as thought it checks for the badge, doesn't find it, adds it, then rechecks again while completely skipping the echo statement.

Comment: for now the code is just check for the badge if it founds it will display the badge and if not found it will just insert the badge and display just text not image.

Comment: why don't you try to put `<img>` tag outside of the condition, I have updated the answer please check.

Comment: That works as it should, however my goal is to have the <img> and following text displayed only when the person wins the badge and it is put into the database. If I put it outside the condition it shows every time you win the battle, not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issues with the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function(){
window.setTimeout('document.victorious.submit()', 4000)
  }
</script>
```

As I suspected my form submit scripts were interfering with each other, this fixed it right up.